# How to solve for these 2 functions?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

Given $f(x) = \sqrt {x^3 - 4}$, solve for $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ where $f(x) = (g \circ h)(x)$

Comment: Are there any restrictions? If not there are some really trivial replies you can give.

Comment: Hopefully you weren't actually told to "solve," as there are uncountably infinitely many solutions. I'd have worded it "...give an example of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ such that $f(x)=(g\circ h)(x).$"

Comment: At this rate they'll never graduate, writing each and every potential solution by hand :(

Comment: No, there are no restrictions. I also think there is something wrong with this question but it was in my maths exam.

Comment: @ABE_Mark45 Waas it multiple choice?

Comment: Would you mind writing your answer if the test is over?

Comment: I wrote those. I believe all of them work.

$h(x) = x$, $g(x) = \sqrt{x^3 - 4}$ &

$h(x) = x^3$, $g(x) = \sqrt{x - 4}$ &

$h(x) = x^3 - 4$, $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$

Answer (score 3):

$h(x)=x^3-4$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{x}.$

Comment: Is this answer also true ?
$h(x) = x$ and $g(x) = \sqrt{x^3 - 4}$

Comment: @ABE_Mark45 Yes. It is another possibility.

Answer (score 2):

$h(x)=x$ and $g(x)=f(x)$ or vice-versa

I'll do you one better:

$f(x)=(g\circ h \circ i)(x)$: $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$;$h(x) = x-4$;$i(x)=x^3$

Don't forget:

$h(x)=x+\texttt{(Meaningless Constant)}$ and $g(x)=f(x)-\texttt{(Meaningless Constant)}$

Comment: Hint: If this is an assignment the preceding answer might make you out to be a bit of a smart-aleck

Comment: And now I want to make a mildly interesting version that spells out a curse word, or adds in needless complexity... :(